# Getting Exception for multiple receivers usimg Swiftmailer

Tags: swiftmailer

follwoing code will send mail to multiple recievers as intended

```html
        $SendObject = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom($string)
                                ->setTo(array('goetz.bewerber@gmx.net','schulze.bewerber@gmail.com','susanne.bewerber@web.de'))
                                ->setHtmlBody($model->bodytext)
                                ->setSubject($model->betreff)
                                ->setTextBody($model->bodytext);
                        $SendObject->send();
```

Unfortunately, I will get Exception if I try like this:

```html
$ZieladresseTest = "'goetz.bewerber@gmx.net','schulze.bewerber@gmail.com','susanne.bewerber@web.de'";

               $SendObject = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom($string)
                                ->setTo(array($ZieladresseTest))
                                ->setHtmlBody($model->bodytext)
                                ->setSubject($model->betreff)
                                ->setTextBody($model->bodytext);
                        $SendObject->send();
```

Exception:

```
Address in mailbox given ['goetz.bewerber@gmx.net','schulze.bewerber@gmail.com','susanne.bewerber@web.de'] 
does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

Any ideas,

1. why exception will be thrown out
2. how to avoid Exception using variables for setTo() ?

Thx in advance. I will give reputation points for every answer solving my problem. Promised!
Edit: Defining variable as an array like this won't fix problem,too:

```
 $ZieladresseTest = array($ZieladresseTest);
```

Comment: Try setting the variable to an array. You're currently trying to set strings in a string. $ZieladresseTest = array('goetz.bewerber@gmx.net','schulze.bewerber@gmail.com','susanne.bewerber@web.de');

Comment: Ur the Best! Please publish ur answer in order to give U reputation points!!

Comment: Uuups:Ur suggestion doesn't work! same error coding like this: ->setTo(array($Zieladresse))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```html
        $SendObject = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom($string)
                                ->setTo(array('goetz.bewerber@gmx.net','schulze.bewerber@gmail.com','susanne.bewerber@web.de'))
                                ->setHtmlBody($model->bodytext)
                                ->setSubject($model->betreff)
                                ->setTextBody($model->bodytext);
                        $SendObject->send();
```

To this

```html
$ZieladresseTest = array('goetz.bewerber@gmx.net','schulze.bewerber@gmail.com','susanne.bewerber@web.de');


        $SendObject = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()->setFrom($string)
                                ->setTo($ZieladresseTest)
                                ->setHtmlBody($model->bodytext)
                                ->setSubject($model->betreff)
                                ->setTextBody($model->bodytext);
                        $SendObject->send();
```